# Change Bootstrap Tab animation and css

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have bootstrap tab in my html and it is working fine. But here I need to change the effect of bootstrap tab. Currently when user click on tab the tab is opened.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="overflow:hidden"><img src="http://designpieces.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/background-image.jpg"> </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-md-6   col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        
                   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel1">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" id="tab1" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Tab1                        ></a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Tab2                        ></a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Tab3                        ></a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                       
                       <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Tab4                        ></a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        
        </div>
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

This is js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/nozp2pge/2/

I want to change the effect and style of bootstrap tab like the following images

**This is first image** [image] .

**When user click on tab1 ( second image)** [image]

What i need is tab with right side arrow is needed like first image . When we click on tab then the entire tab view is replaced by the corresponding  tab content with anyone of the animation with back button (like second image). when user click on back button the entire tab(first image ) need to show  again.

for this i write the code but that is not completed and not perfect

```
<script>
        $("#tab1").on("click",function(){

            $(".panel").hide();
            $(".panel1").show();
        });

</script>
```

Please help to resolve this .

Comment: Can you create a bootply so we can understand better what you;re trying to achieve?

Comment: please check my jsfiddle . I Want work this tabs like the images i provided .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this can be done using CSS pseudo-elements.

```
selector:pseudo-element {
  property: value;
}
```

You should always try to use CSS before JavaScript or jQuery if CSS will do the job. Just add a class to the collapsed headings and style accordingly.

Notice how I added a `collapsed` class to the section headers that have panels that are collapsed by default.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" class="collapsed">Tab2</a>
```

Then styled the headings using just CSS

```
.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel-title a:active,
.panel-title a:focus,
.panel-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-title a:before {
  content: "<";
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed {
  text-align: left;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed:before {
  content: "";
}
.panel-title a.collapsed:after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute; 
  right: 30px;
}
```

Here's your updated fiddle with what I'm talking about https://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/nozp2pge/4/.

**EDITED**

Ah, ok. I understand now. To accomplish this, you will need jQuery and will want to check which heading is being clicked and hide that panel's siblings.

```
$(function () {
  $('.panel-title a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel').siblings().toggle();
  });
});
```

`.toggle()` is used so that it shows the other panels when the heading is clicked again.

I've also added the `collapsed` class to the first heading so that that panel is hidden, like in your first picture above. Here's the updated fiddle with these changes for you to review. https://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/nozp2pge/5/

Comment: Thank you friend.But i need some modification as per my question . I saw your jsfiddle . In there when someone click tab one then the tab1 is coming with back arrow,and the other tabs are showing  , that is great . But when someone click  tab1 i need to show the content of tab1 only and need to hide all other tab . So when someone click tab1 he only see tab1 heading and it contents . For to see other tabs he need to click the tab1 back arrow .This is what i need .

Comment: @Felix see my edited response/answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: also,how we can change the default tab animation style. ? like when clicking the tab1 then any animation like http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation_delay or http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: You would just create the desired keyframe and then set it to the element you want animated. Here's the updated jsfiddle for you with a demo shake. https://jsfiddle.net/nozp2pge/7/

Comment: i have other doubt , i will ask as new question.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560231/how-to-change-bootstrap-responsive-style