# How to change bootstrap responsive style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

We are planing to change the responsive nature of bootstrap in other manner . Please see the  current html

```js
$(function () {
 $('.panel-title a').on('click', function () {
   $(this).closest('.panel').siblings().toggle();
   });
 });
```

```css
.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel-title a:active,
.panel-title a:focus,
.panel-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-title a:before {
  content: "<";
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed {
  text-align: left;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed:before {
  content: "";
}
.panel-title a.collapsed:after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute; 
  right: 30px;
}

.panel-body {
  animation: shake;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="overflow:hidden"><img src="http://designpieces.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/background-image.jpg"> </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-md-6   col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        
                   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default  panel1">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title wobble">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="tab1" href="#collapse1" class="collapsed">Tab1</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" class="collapsed">Tab2</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" class="collapsed">Tab3</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                       
                       <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4" class="collapsed">Tab4</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        
        </div>
```

Here when window is resized or view in mobile devise the list group is showing like these . Please see the image

[image]

But we need to change this .When window is resized and it's width is less than some amount then we want to show a arrow or settings icon on the right side part of the window (right side of the image).

Please see the desired output

[image]

When we click on the settings icon then the image is replaced by
     content in the list group with close icon. So that user can see the list group in full window without image and he can operate all action. After this he can close that list group by clicking close button. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: So you want the tab label to not display and only the icon indicators at smaller screen resolutions?

Comment: I think I understand, one second... I'll update that fiddle.

Comment: yes . That is i wanted . but the icon indicator on the top right part of the image . When clicking on icon it show only tabs.And the tabs come with any animation effect

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Once sec...

Comment: Was a little tricky as I had to make sure that the image showed again when the screen size was resized back to a larger screen. I've added font icons from FontAwesome so I could use the cog icon. Let me know if this is what you're looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/nozp2pge/9/

Comment: I forgot to re-add the `hidden-xs` class back to the right column so that it hides on resize after the toggle button is clicked. Here's the fix for that https://jsfiddle.net/nozp2pge/10/

Comment: could you please write it as answer.Also is there any possibility to show JSFiddle result on separate window

Comment: I've included the code snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When window is resized and it's width is less than some amount then we want to show a arrow or settings icon on the right side part of the window (right side of the image).

This can be accomplish by adding an element with the desired icon and using Bootstrap's helper class of `visible-xs` like:

```
<span id="toggle" class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></span>
```

And add `hidden-xs` to the right column so that the tab accordions don't show at the same `xs` screen resolutions.

You'll then need to use `$(window).width()` to detect the window size and if the window size is a certain size or less, it will allow the trigger (click) of the cog icon to hide the image and show the tab content.

If you increase the size, the image reappears with the tabs to the right.

**Edit**

> After this he can close that list group by clicking close button.

I see what you're wanting to do now.

So, first I changed the font icon to the icon matching your image.

```
<span id="toggle" class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x">
```

The click trigger initially would only work if you had resized the window. You can add the same `click` event outside the `.resize()` function to correct that. (see the comments in the updated JS)

So that the user can hide and show (toggle) between the tabs and image, you will use `.toggle()` and to change the icon image use `.toggleClass()`

```
$(this).children().toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square');
```

**Note**: Keep the `.resize()` function in there so that it all still works when resizing the window on larger screens. As Ron pointed out, *I also fixed the `.resize()` function to behave the same*.

> instead of shake how can i change animation to Slide toggle from right to left

**TLDR;**

@keyframes allows you to control the intermediate steps in a CSS animation sequence by establishing waypoints along the animation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes). I've added a `slideInRight` keyframe rule for you to see the differences between that and the shake. I suggest reading up on @keyframes if you're looking to implement this kind of stuff into your projects so that you can create your own in the future.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-title a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel').siblings().toggle();
  });

  // this takes care of screensizes that start off at small sizes
  // like tablets or mobile devices
  $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square');
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    $(this).closest('div').siblings().toggleClass('hidden-xs');
  });

  // provide the same size affect and fall back on desktop sizes
  // when resizing window.
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize < 768) { // BS breaking point for -xs
      $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children().toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square');
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        $(this).closest('div').siblings().toggleClass('hidden-xs');
      });
    } else {
      $('#toggle').prev().show();
      $('#toggle').closest('div').siblings().addClass('hidden-xs');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel-title a:active,
.panel-title a:focus,
.panel-title a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-title a:before {
  content: "\f177";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed {
  text-align: left;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed:before {
  content: "";
}
.panel-title a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\f054";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: absolute; 
  right: 30px;
}

.panel-body {
  animation: slideInRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.img-container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;  
}
#toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInRight;
  animation-name: slideInRight;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 img-container" style="overflow:hidden"><img src="http://designpieces.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/background-image.jpg"> 
   <span id="toggle" class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i></span>
   </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 hidden-xs">
        
                   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default  panel1">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title wobble">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="tab1" href="#collapse1" class="collapsed">Tab1</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" class="collapsed">Tab2</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" class="collapsed">Tab3</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                       
                       <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4" class="collapsed">Tab4</a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: But here when clicking on setting icon nothing happen ? I can't see the list when clicking on setting icon .

Comment: and for some reason the stetting icon is not showing and the result have no change . Please see this in small window https://jsfiddle.net/nozp2pge/10/embedded/result/

Comment: @Felix, you need to adjust the if `windowSize` argument to your desired breaking point, because as it stands written, clicking on the cog icon only works if the windowSize is less than `700`. Per Bootstrap, their breaking point is 768px.

Comment: Not sure if it's something with jsfiddle, if you click `Expand snippet` and resize the window, it shows and works as expected.

Comment: I see what you're talking about now, you need to add the `click` event for `#toggle` outside of the `.resize()` so that it doesn't just trigger on the resizing of the window.

Comment: really thank you friend .Now also i see the answer in window width 456 , + sign is coming and then going .now also the tab in the half of the page . Actually what i need is ,seeing in window width 456 then need to show image with + sign . Click the + sign then image is replaced and hided by tabs with close button.  When he click on close button then he can see the image again with + button . That is + button need to clickable . If + button is clicked then he can see the tab only not the image , and clicking on tab he an see the tab content . Close tab he can see the image again

Comment: @ChrisYongchu your answer is fantastic . and it is working good in run code snippets . But felix is maybe testing by run code snippets clicking full page option in the top right and then resizing the window . In there it is not working . That is he confused

Comment: @Ron, thanks! and Felix, if this answers and meet all your requirements, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: instead of shake how can i change animation to Slide toggle from right to left https://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/ ? . Thank you

Comment: @Felix, see revised answer and my suggestion for you. Happy coding! :)